# Why do these two methods shows different results?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I was trying to fetch an arraylist from Firestore using coroutine kotlin. I wrote two different methods to get same result. These are the methods

**MethodA**

```
fun methodA(type: String) {
           CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
             val myList = mutableListOf<Product>()
             val job = async(IO) {
              db.collection("Products").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapShot ->
                 snapShot.forEach { subSnapShot ->
                    if (subSnapShot.exists()) {
                        if (subSnapShot["name"]?.equals(type) == true) {
                            val category = type
                            val url = subSnapShot["url"].toString()
                            val type = subSnapShot["type"].toString()
                            val item = Product(url, category, subSnapShot.id, type)
                            myList.add(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
            myList
         }.await()
          temp.postValue(job)
       }
      }
```

**MethodB**

```
 fun methodB(type: String) {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
              val myList = mutableListOf<Product>()
               db.collection("Products").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapShot ->
                snapShot.forEach { subSnapShot ->
                  if (subSnapShot.exists()) {
                      if (subSnapShot["name"]?.equals(type) == true) {
                          val category = type
                          val url = subSnapShot["url"].toString()
                          val type = subSnapShot["type"].toString()
                          val item = Product(url, category, subSnapShot.id, type)
                          myList.add(item)
                      }
                  }
              }
          }.await()
        temp.postValue(myList)
    }
}
```

I was expecting to get same result from these two methods but **MethodA** returns an empty list while **MethodB** returns list of item. How do i fix my **MethodA** if i fetch list like this unlike **MethodB**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these will reliably work. It's a race condition, and you got lucky with MethodB. It won't consistently be successful.

The problem is that even though you are calling `await()` on the task, the callback will not necessarily be run before `await()` returns.

A listener is called asynchronously. Code below it continues running in the same thread it was added from. Then the code inside the listener is run some time in the future (probably only a couple milliseconds, but still after your other code is run) when the result is complete.

Since you're using coroutines, you should be using the return value of `await()` and not be adding listeners. You also need to use `try/catch` in case it fails. Then your code can be run sequentially in the order it appears, taking advantage of one of the best features of coroutines.

In practice, you should be using an existing CoroutineScope that you cancel at the appropriate time, not creating a one-off CoroutineScope to launch a single coroutine and then throwing it away. But I'm leaving that in this example since it's not what you were asking about.

Here's how to properly do this (except for the CoroutineScope part):

```
fun methodC(type: String) {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        try { 
            db.collection("Products").get().await()
                .filter { it.exists() && it["name"]?.equals(type) == true }
                .map { subSnapShot ->
                    val category = type
                    val url = subSnapShot["url"].toString()
                    val type = subSnapShot["type"].toString()
                    Product(url, category, subSnapShot.id, type)
                }
                .let(temp::postValue)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to query products.", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have one query here , i wanna ask why async cannot wait by calling await() method in MethodA till the listener finish its job? Why the coroutine thread is waiting by calling await() method in MethodB ?

Comment: `addOnSuccessListener()` is not intended for coroutines. It is a callback that is **queued** to run on another thread once the job is complete. When you `await` the Task in the coroutine, the task is complete, but the listener is only queued to run. Depending on which thread your coroutine happened to be running on and the internal design of the Firebase library, there is no guarantee whether the listener will be called yet when you await the task. The task is definitely complete, but maybe its listeners have not been notified yet.

Comment: Basically: Never mix listeners with coroutines because the behavior will be undefined. There are many factors that could influence it to either work or not work according to your expectations, so there is not really any reason to try to understand what is causing the different behavior because you'll never want to try to rely on consistent behavior with this. Plus, one of the primary reasons to use coroutines is so you can avoid using callbacks in the first place.

Comment: okay ..Thanks.. i got it now . Also i wanna know How do i manage my coroutine scope ?

Comment: On Android, 90% of the time you just use `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope` which are already managed for you. If your code is not in a ViewModel, Activity, or Fragment, and needs its own scope for running coroutines, you could in some cases make a CoroutineScope constructor parameter in the class so a ViewModel, Activity, or Fragment can pass its scope in for you to use. This would make sense if the class lives for the same amount of time as one of those higher level classes. But if it doesn't, or your working in a repository class, then you need to create your own.

Comment: You do that using something like `val scope = MainScope(CoroutineName("My class scope"))` as a property in your class, and wherever you have code to tear down your class when its about to be destroyed, you should call `scope.cancel()`.